# Flutter Firestore retrieve all document contents using async

Tags: flutter, async-await, google-cloud-firestore, future, completion

Messages are not being returned when called using print(await _getAllMessages());

I am attempting to retrieve the data from every document within a specified collection. I would like to turn this document into a single string and print this to the console.

_getAllMessages() async {
    // print(data["message"]));

```
String messages = "Copy of message body below: \n";

Firestore.instance
    .collection('rooms')
    .document('roomA')
    .collection('messages')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) => data.documents.forEach(
          (doc) => messages += doc.data.toString(),
        ));

return messages;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems, first you should use the `.getDocuments` function instead of the `.listen` , second the return should be inside the `.getDocuments` function (or use async await).

```
_getAllMessages() async {

   String messages = "Copy of message body below: \n";  
   Firestore.instance
   .collection('rooms')
   .document('roomA')
   .collection('messages')
   .getDocuments((data) => data.documents.forEach(
       (doc) => messages += doc.data.toString(), );
       return messages;
   );
}
```